# How to find the "slug" of a NFT collection posted on opensea using the contract address?

Tags: blockchain, nft, python, opensea

The opensea api uses collection "slugs" in their get requests to identify collections, however, I don't see an easy way to find these "slugs". I know that you can enter the page of the respective collection and find it in the url, but that is quite ineffective if I want to fetch multiple ones. Does anyone know of a more effective way to find them using the contract address or something? preferably using python and web3 or the opensea api.

Comment: See https://docs.opensea.io/reference/retrieving-a-single-contract.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it from the URL: https://opensea.io/collection/akidcalledbeast -> Slug is `akidcalledbeast`.

`docs.opensea.io/reference/retrieving-a-single-contract` is no longer there.